# What is a shell script, makefile and ant file

Tags: java, c, makefile

I had two homework, one  C program and the other Java. I did them but the professor ask for:

> Include a build, test and execution script (e.g. shell script, makefile, ant file) for your implementation.

I don't understand what he want, it's not only the code?

Comment: Incoming downvotes, please do your own `Homework`!

Comment: Why don't you ask him?

Comment: The professors wants `.java` source **as well as** any of 1) `compileandrun.bat` 2) `makefile` 3) `build.xml`

Comment: Most probably he wants also an environment to work with your code: build it, test it, execute it. But you should ask him, not us.

Comment: I did taught this year at the University, and it always amazes me how the supposed Y generation is not able to search the f*ing web.... Asking on a forum takes more time than googling (or asking your teacher)!

Answer (score 4):

I'm guessing you are using Linux. You really should have googled ...

A [shell script](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_script) is some executable text file, usually starting with `#!/bin/sh` which contain shell commands (perhaps shell builtins like `cd`). Read e.g. the [advanced bash scripting guide](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/) for more.

A [Makefile](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Makefile) is the default configuration file for `make`. GNU make has a [nice documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/index.html) which you should read.

[ANT](http://ant.apache.org/) is another builder program (a bit like `make`, more focused for Java application).

There are many other builder programs, you may want to consider [omake](http://omake.metaprl.org/index.html) instead of `make` or `ant` (but ask your teacher first).